# When I save app I get "Namespace: Is not allowed"

Tags: facebook

If I go to manage my Facebook app, edit my "basic" settings and try to hit save it gives the error:
"Error
Namespace: Is not allowed"

Even if I don't change anything: simply going to the "Basic Settings" and hitting Save gives the same error.

The namespace I have used is in development so I would prefer not to state it publicly at this time.
The namespace *does* work (i.e. apps.facebook.com/ does go to the correct place), but I cannot make any changes to my app settings due to this error.

I have tried different browsers in case it was a browser quirk, but the same thing happens.

Anybody have any idea what might be causing this?

## UPDATE

Same thing still happening.  In case anybody else hits this same issue, I found that I am able to modify the app settings via the API even though the web interface gives this error.
If its useful, here's what my JS looked like to do that:

```
function changeIt() {
  var appDomainArray = new Array();
  appDomainArray.push("www.<some-domain>.com");
  FB.api(
  "/<app-id-here>?access_token=<access-token-here>",
  "POST",
  {
    "canvas_url": "http://www.<some-domain>.com/home",
    "secure_canvas_url": "https://www.<some-domain>.com/home",
    "website_url": "https://www.<some-domain>.com/home",
    "mobile_web_url": "https://www.<some-domain>.com/home",
    "app_domains": appDomainArray
  },
  function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response && !response.error) {
      alert('done!');
    } else {
      alert('fail!');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because an app namespace is missing, and empty namespace is not allowed.

```
"app_namespace" :"myappnamespace1234" // some unique string
"canvas_url": "http://www.<some-domain>.com/home",
```